# no cerrar popover a menos que sea con el link

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

cuando hago click fuera del popover se cierra el popover, no quiero que se cierre

```js
$(function() {
  // Enables popover
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="<div class='demo'>
            <div id='adentro'>
              hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhoooooooolaaaaaaa
            </div>
         </div>">popover</a>
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada si hemos resuelto tu problema. Si no, dinos que te falla o falta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Para habilitar solo con el click , se debería cambiar el `trigger` a `click` , una forma es como añadió @lois , otra es añadir al constructor desde Js.

**Ejm**

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({trigger: 'click'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="<div class='demo'>
            <div id='adentro'>
              hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhoooooooolaaaaaaa
            </div>
</div>">popover</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si le quitas el `data-trigger="focus"` haciendo click lo habilitas y hasta que no vuelves a darle al propio elemento no se oculta.

Con `Focus` le estas diciendo que solo aparezca cuando el boton tenga el foco con lo que si pulsas otro sitio, se oculta.

```js
$(function() {
  // Enables popover
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="<div class='demo'>
            <div id='adentro'>
              hhhhhhhhhhoooolaaaa
            </div>
         </div>">popover</a>
```